# SourceTree and Git, http-push failed

Tags: git, curl, push

I'm writing some code for a customer.

He gave me a remote server where I can push my commits. When I push, that's what's happening:

[image: Screen]

Windows says I have a problem with libcurl-4.dll, the library is missing.

I tried to install via Curl's website the right DLL to fix the problem ... didn't work.

When I push on bitbucket / github, everything runs smoothly.

Any idea in mind ?

Comment: Did you try re-installing source tree? It may be worth trying via the command line as well.

Answer (score 2):

Update 2016 ( 3 years later)

The [latest git-for-windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) [based on msys2 project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35099458/6309) and [which replaces msysgit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309) should fix the issue.

Just in case, search for other `libcurl*.dll` in your system and remove them.

---

Original answer (Oct 2013)

Make sure your SourceTree does reference an **[msysgit 1.8.4](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=3&q=full%20installer%20official%20git&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount)** (which you can specify during the installation):

[image: http://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/d/dameleon/20130321/20130321184036.jpg]

msysgit 1.8.3 (Git-1.8.3-preview20130601.exe) didn't include by mistake the `libcurl-4.dll`:

[image: http://qph.cf.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-fbd8f3086110a41ec7694d6a137574ad]

---

> When i push with bitbucket or github no problem, because they use an another protocol ?

If the url for those services is **`ssh://`** (instead of `https://`), then `libcurl` wouldn't be involved at all, and that would explain why those pushes succeed.

Comment: Just curious, how did you try out these steps and get the images?

Comment: @ansh0l from http://translate.google.fr/translate?hl=fr&sl=ja&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fdameleon.hatenablog.com%2Fentry%2F2013%2F03%2F21%2F185412 and http://www.quora.com/Git-revision-control/How-do-I-get-rid-of-the-error-message-The-program-cant-start-because-libcurl-4-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer-Try-reinstalling-the-program-to-fix-the-problem-when-trying-to-push-after-installing-TortoiseGit-and-Git-1-8-3-preview20130601-exe-Win-7-x64

Comment: I must try your solution. Right now i must use the command line just for push, no problem with this way. So i guessed, no problem with the GIT system, so i tried to use this last with sourceTree in options. Didn't work.